# AssertionError { state: 'pending' }

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I try to use a compilation of differents stacks:

**Mocha** – test runner

**Chai** – assertion library

**webdriverio** – browser control bindings

**Selenium** – browser abstraction and running factory

**PhantomJS** – fast headless browser

so i launch a selenium server like this

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar
```

and i launch my test like this

```
 mocha test.js -t 10000
```

Here is my ***test.js***

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = { desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'phantomjs' } };
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);


describe('Test example.com', function(){
    before(function(done) {
        client.init().url('/* my website */');
        done();
        //client.pause(5000);
        var chai = require('chai');
        global.expect = chai.expect;
        chai.Should();

    });


    describe('Check homepage', function(){
        it('should wait 3 secondes', function() {
            client.pause(3000);
        });

        it('should see the correct title', function() {
            client.waitForValue('#logoHeaderNav', 3000);
            client.url('/* my website */');
            client.getTitle().should.be.equal('/*my title*/');

        });
    });

    after(function(done) {
    client.end();
    done();
    });
});
```

and the result i get is :

```
# mocha test.js -t 10000


  Test example.com
    Check homepage
      ✓ should wait 3 secondes
      1) should see the correct title


  1 passing (108ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test example.com Check homepage should see the correct title:
     AssertionError: expected { state: 'pending' } to equal '/*my title */'
      at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:90:35)
```

any ideas of something i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: In your wdio configuration file, do you have 'sync: true,'?

Comment: has this been solved?

Answer (score 3):

WebdriverIO commands all return promises, which is what the `{ state: 'pending' }` is in your error message.

To get around this, you'll want to use Chai's "as-promised" plugin. [The official site has a page](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/transferpromises.html) detailing how to get this set up for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the client.waitForValue('#logoHeaderNav', 3000); statement and see if it works.